# Issue with Caesar Cipher and while loops

Tags: python, encryption, while-loop

I'm making this Caesar Cipher decoder and I want the program to print every single option (the 26 ways it could be shifted). However, when I run my code nothing shows, what was my error. If you know please tell me, I'm new to coding and in need of help.

```
import sys
import time

L2I = dict(zip("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",range(26)))
I2L = dict(zip(range(26),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))

msg = ("What is the intercepted message \n")
for character in msg:
  sys.stdout.write(character)
  sys.stdout.flush()
  time.sleep(0.1)
msg_ans = input("> ")
msg_ans = msg_ans.strip()

shift = 0
def decipher(msg_ans,shift): 
  while shift < 26: 
    for i in msg_ans.upper():
      if i.isalpha() == True : 
        msg_ans += I2L[ (L2I[i]+ shift)%26 ]
        shift += 1
      else: 
        msg_ans += i
        shift += 1 
  print (msg_ans)
decipher(msg_ans,shift)
```

I expect it to output the 26 ways it can be shifted. However when I put the word 'Hello' I get 'HelloHFNOSMKSTXRQZBGWUCDHBAJLQLKTVAVVFIO' instead of 'IFMMP JGNNQ ...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues. First, you're incrementing `shift` every time you check a single character. In reality, you only want to increment it after each time you cycle completely through the message. You should also move the initialization into the function. There's no reason to pass `shift` in, since you're just trying all 26 possibilities in order.

```
def decipher(msg_ans): 
    shift = 0
    while shift < 26: 
        for i in msg_ans.upper():
            if i.isalpha() == True : 
                msg_ans += I2L[ (L2I[i]+ shift)%26 ]
            else: 
                msg_ans += i
        shift += 1
    print (msg_ans)
```

At this point, though, there's no reason to use a `while` loop instead of a `for`:

```
def decipher(msg_ans): 
    for shift in range(26): 
        for i in msg_ans.upper():
            if i.isalpha() == True : 
                msg_ans += I2L[ (L2I[i]+ shift)%26 ]
            else: 
                msg_ans += i
    print (msg_ans)
```

The other issue is that you're just appending the new characters to the end of your input string. You don't specify what form you actually want it in, so let's say you want it in a list of strings. You'll need to initialize the list, build a temporary string on each iteration, and then append the temporary string to the list:

```
def decipher(msg_ans): 
    possible_messages = []
    for shift in range(26): 
        decoded_msg = ''
        for i in msg_ans.upper():
            if i.isalpha() == True : 
                decoded_msg += I2L[ (L2I[i]+ shift)%26 ]
            else: 
                decoded_msg += i
        possible_messages.append(decoded_msg)
    return possible_messages
```

Then just print the result of your invocation of the function:

```
 print(decipher(msg_ans))
```

Comment: Thanks, this explained the problem in my code well and gave me a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

msg should be like this

```
msg = "What is the intercepted message \n"
```

Also you probably want to print instead of return here

```
return msg_ans
```